# unable to export HDFS FUSE mount over NFS

Tags: hdfs, fuse

I m using CDH 4.3.0 and I have mounted hdfs using FUSE on my edge node. And the fuse mount point automatically changes the permissions from root:root to hdfs:hadoop.
When I try to export it over NFS, it throws a permissions error to me. Can anyone help me how to get around this. I ve read somewhere that it works only in kernel versions 2.6.27 and above, and mine is 2.6.18...Is this true ?

my mount command gives this output for hdfs fuse:
fuse on /hdfs-root/hdfs type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,allow_other,default_permissions)

my /etc/exports looks like this:
/hdfs-root/hdfs/user   *(fsid=0,rw,wdelay,anonuid=101,anongid=492,sync,insecure,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)

my /etc/fstab looks like this:
hadoop-fuse-dfs#hdfs:: /hdfs-root/hdfs fuse allow_other,usetrash,rw 2 0
:/hdfs-root/hdfs/user          /hdfsbkp     nfs     rw

the first line is for FUSE, and 2nd line is to export the mounted HDFS over NFS..
when I run mount -a, I get the following error...

"mount: :/hdfs-root/hdfs/user failed, reason given by server: Permission denied"

Also, I tried to change the ownership of FUSE mount to root:root, but it wouldnt let me do that either...by the way, we are using kerberos as authentication method to access hadoop...

Any help is really appreciated!!!

Comment: i m readding my entries in /etc/fstab, /etc/exports below...

Comment: /etc/fstab is : hadoop-fuse-dfs#hdfs://namenodeuri:8020 /hdfs-root/hdfs fuse allow_other,usetrash,rw 2 0